# Asp.net equivivalent to Model.objects.get(name=Somebody) in django

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have User table and it has username field. How do I do something like this in asp.net:

```
user = User.objects.get(username="Somebody")
```

i.e. get a user by its username.

I don't want to use a raw sql query.  How do I get the data?

Comment: What is ´User` object? is it a collection?

Comment: Search for "LINQ" and "Entity Framework".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the `User.objects` return any implementation of `IEnumerable<User>` for you, you could use linq to get by userName property, for sample:

Add the namespace to use `Linq`:

```
using System.Linq;
```

and try this:

```
// in this case, we are considering that User is a collection
var user = User.First(x => x.username == "Somebody");
```

If you are using Entity Framework, you could try using the context:

```
var user = context.DbSet<User>().First(x => x.username == "Somebody");
```

See more samples about linq here in [101-LINQ-Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 0):

if User is a dataset try the following:

```
User.Tables[0].Columns["Somebody"]
```